# Airflow BashOperator freezes after some time

Tags: ssh, airflow, airflow-2.x

BashOperator executes a ssh command that runs process on another server and waits for its execution. Problem is a process on the other server freezes after some time (usually a few hours) whilst Airflow task is still in running mode. What might be the cause of a problem?
Problem exists on both Airflow 1 and Airflow 2 which are running on the same server.

I read that ssh sessions freeze after some time so I added theses configurations https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200239/how-can-i-keep-my-ssh-sessions-from-freezing
but unfortunately it didn't help :(
Also, I tried using SSHOperator instead, but I faced that problem again.

Comment: did you get any fix for this ? I am facing the same problem with SSHOperator

Comment: @CoronaVirus, the problem actually got resolved by itself after some time, I'm not sure what was the issue